# Can't set paint to canvas.drawBitmap()

Tags: android, kotlin, android-canvas

I follow a tutorial and the code is error in the line of drawBitmap()

```
val bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.absolutePath)
val resultBmp = bmp.copy(bmp.config,true)
val paint = Paint()
paint.colorFilter = ColorFilter.lighting(Color.LightGray, Color.Magenta)
val canvas = android.graphics.Canvas(resultBmp)
canvas.drawBitmap(resultBmp,0f,0f, paint
```

I tried but the solution doesn't work

```
val paint : Paint? = null
```

Comment: Hi, Vy! Could you provide a stack trace?

Comment: Hi Ivan, It was: None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
drawBitmap(Bitmap, Rect?, Rect, Paint?) defined in android.graphics.Canvas
drawBitmap(Bitmap, Rect?, RectF, Paint?) defined in android.graphics.Canvas
drawBitmap(Bitmap, Float, Float, Paint?) defined in android.graphics.Canvas

Comment: There is some error with types here. You are trying to use this overloading: drawBitmap(Bitmap, Float, Float, Paint?). Looking at your code, floats and paint is fine, so check your `resultBmp` variable type.

Comment: I've just updated to show all my code, it was red in Paint? type and I don't know why.

Comment: Please, post your imports. Maybe you got the wrong dependency. I tried your code myself, and drawBitmap compiled just fine.

Comment: Hi Ivan: import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.ColorFilter
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Paint
import androidx.core.net.toFile
import androidx.core.net.toUri
import androidx.work.CoroutineWorker
import androidx.work.WorkerParameters
import androidx.work.workDataOf
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileOutputStream